# Organizar array

Tags: php, array, otimização

Bom como posso organizar esse array sem precisar de usar um loop

Array original

```
["Entrada" => 4, "Prato principal" => 1]
```

Array pretendido

```
[["Entrada",4],["Prato principal",1]]
```

ok entendi o que vcs querem dizer... eu tinha feito em loop mesmo mais acabei alterando pelo da resposta vou voltar para o loop que que e mais fácil a compreensão. Agora acabou que aconteceu uma otimização mesmo, pois peguei o codigo e adaptei ele pra outra parte que estava fazendo 2 consultas no mysql, ficando assim

```
      $stmt = getConn()->query("SELECT hash,nome,categoria FROM produto");
      $qryProduto = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_GROUP|PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
      $qryProdNome = array_reduce(array_keys($qryProduto), function($novo, $chave) use ($qryProduto){
        $novo[$chave] = $qryProduto[$chave][0]['nome'];
      return $novo;
      });
      $qryProdCateg = array_reduce(array_keys($qryProduto), function($novo, $chave) use ($qryProduto){
        $novo[$chave] = $qryProduto[$chave][0]['categoria'];
      return $novo;
      });
      /*$stmt = getConn()->query("SELECT hash,categoria FROM produto");
      $qryProdCateg = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_GROUP|PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
      $qryProdCateg = array_map('reset', $qryProdCateg);
      $qryProdCateg = array_map('reset', $qryProdCateg);*/
```

Estava fazendo 2 consultas uma para produto e outra para categoria, não tem como eu junta esse 2 reduce de uma vez não? ou n a necessidade já que evitei uma busca no mysql

NOTA ah e um detalhe, escrevi o loop no site ideone e percebi que com o loop, o tempo de resposta era igual 2ms, mais com o loop o peso era cerca de 600kb menor

Tem como melhorar essa logica? o que ta pegando e que estou fazendo 2 loop pra organizar a resposta final, e isso está me incomodando

```
$stmt = getConn()->query("SELECT id,unix_timestamp(data) AS data FROM loginclient");
  $qryLoginClient = $stmt->fetchAll();
  $totaluser = $stmt->rowCount();
  $onoff = ( $totaluser > 0 ? true : false ); // preparação para lazzyload
  $usuarioHj = 0;
  $usuarioOntem = 0;
  $bugfix = 0;
  $org_user = [];
  foreach($qryLoginClient as $data){
    if(strtotime($vhoje) <= $data['data']):
      $usuarioHj++;
    elseif(strtotime($vontem) <= $data['data']):
      $usuarioOntem++;
    endif;
    $maskdate = date("d-m-Y", $data['data'] );
    if($bugfix <= 15):
      ( !isset($org_user[$maskdate]) ? $org_user[$maskdate] = 1 : $org_user[$maskdate]++ );
    endif;
    $bugfix++;
  }
  foreach($org_user as $item => $id){
    unset($org_user[$item]);
    $org_user[] = [$item,$id];
  }
  $bugfix = ( $usuarioOntem == 0 ? 1 : $usuarioOntem );
  $taxa_crescimento = ceil(($usuarioHj-$usuarioOntem)/$bugfix*100);
  $respNovoUsuario = [$totaluser,$taxa_crescimento,$org_user];
```

Comment: Defina "organizar". Não dá para saber o que deseja. Ainda mais com a *tag* de otimização. E qual o objetivo? O *array*  é exatamente este?

Comment: O que você quer não tem lógica; veja, no array original, as arrows do elemento entrada indica que aquele valor vai ser definido pra aquele elemento. No array pretendido você está separando os elementos, então a leitura do segundo seria: array(0){ com elementos 0,1 com os valores "entrada" e "4" }.

Comment: @Maniero sim o array e esse, mas a informação e mutável pode ter mais índices ou menos

Comment: É impossível fazer sem um *loop*, o que pode fazer é usar uma abstração que o esconda. Sinceramente, isso não é otimização, é o contrário. Pode deixar mais curto, mas muita vezes menos legível tb. Na verdade neste caso eu faço mais curto com o laço, e com mais performance, portanto é daqueles requisitos que não faz o menor sentido.

Comment: @Maniero blz entendi, agora editei o post acabou que essa resposta me ajudou com outro problema que não tava gostando muito de como estava, se tiver como da uma olhada e ver se precisa de modificação

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pessoalmente aconselho a utilizar o *loop* normal mesmo e fazer o que tem a fazer que é mais simples de ler, gerando uma solução menos complexa. Existem muitos outros cenários que seriam aconselháveis de fazer com funções nativas pois tem funções diretas e exatas para o resultado que prentede, que não é o caso.

Consegue uma solução com funções nativas utilizando por exemplo  [`array_reduce`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-reduce.php) e [`array_keys`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-keys.php). 
A ideia é "reduzir" pelas chaves do array original gerando uma nova entrada para cada chave. Para poder ir buscar o valor associado à chave utiliza o array original.

Exemplo:

```
$arr = ["Entrada" => 4, "Prato principal" => 1];

$res = array_reduce(array_keys($arr), function($novoArr, $chave) use ($arr){
    $novoArr[] = Array($chave, $arr[$chave]);
    return $novoArr;
});
```

Que lhe dá o seguinte resultado:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(7) "Entrada"
    [1]=>
    int(4)
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(15) "Prato principal"
    [1]=>
    int(1)
  }
}
```

[Veja este resultado no Ideone](https://ideone.com/7Bl00I)

Note que tive que fazer `use ($arr)` para poder aceder ao array original dentro do *callback* passado ao `array_reduce`.

### Com loop normal

Agora compare a solução anterior com uma utilizando um *loop* normal:

```
$res = Array();
foreach($arr as $key => $val){
    $res[] = Array($key, $val); 
}
```

Não só é muito mais simples, como mais perfomatico.

### Conclusão

Utilize apenas as funções nativas para o que faz sentido. A própria transformação que está a fazer parece não ter muito sentido, pois acaba por ter exatamente a mesma informação mas com mais profundidade, mais um nível no array. E mesmo num `foreach` normal consegue aceder à informação em ambas as versões.

Comment: blz dei uma atualizada na duvida, ja que chegou a uma conclusão

Comment: @Willian O código que mostrou agora na pergunta não é muito claro para mim o seu objetivo, mas digo já de avanço que provavelmente não é a melhor ideia. Qual a utilização que quer dar ? Quer guardar um array para os nomes e outro para as categorias é isso ? Como aparte o problema de "performance" provavelmente vem do facto de estar a fazer duas consultas que se calhar consegue fazer numa só.

Comment: correto acaba que usei um loop, tava meio cansado nem vi que era a mesma ideia do loop mais de qualquer forma obrigado, é sim acabou que reduzi uma consulta no banco, obrigado, ah e a melhor forma de fazer isso e so fazer uma busca e guarda no array e trabalha esse array para ele sempre chegar nas infomações que precisso?

Comment: @Willian Sim é isso, guarda no array tudo o que precisa e depois usa dai. Mas para guardar no array apenas precisa de 1 loop.

Comment: pronto esclareceu as duvidas agora so tenho mais uma sobre otimização